# Get a decimal to show 3 digits after the dot

Tags: c#, models, petapoco

I got a model that, among others, contains this:

```
public decimal MyValue { get; set; }
```

Using PetaPoco this is transformed into a SQL field in a table. But the data type beeing created in SQL, is `decimal(18,2)`.
I wan't it to show 3 decimals, not just 2 - how and where can i change this?